# Updating MySQL Database using form variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I currently have a page that I'm building locally that is an online approval system for design/creative that I do for clients. With that said, I have a portal where the client can login to a specific order view their orders and approve creative for each item for that overall project.

Visual Reference:
[image]

Here is the problem:

When a user clicks on the thumbs up, to approve OR the thumbs down, to reject. The value of that radio button does not get written to that file status column into the database for that creative.

I am using a variable name (the specific creatives ID) for the radio button grouping. How can I get the value of that specific grouping to be written to the database column that references the status for each creative?

```
<?php $uploadID = $row_order_upload['id']; ?>
<?php $reviewID = $row_order_upload['id'] . 'a'; ?>

<p class="document_item">
  <span class="document_status_container">
    <span class="document_status status_pendingapproval"><?php echo $row_order_upload['file_status']; ?></span><a data-options="width:<?php echo $row_order_upload['file_width'] ?>, height:<?php echo $row_order_upload['file_height'] ?>" href="http://localhost:8888/-portal/user_data/<?php echo $row_order_upload['file_name']; ?>" class="fancybox_swf"><?php echo $row_order_upload['file_width'].'x'.$row_order_upload['file_height'] ?></a></span>
  </p>
    <div class="adStatus_container">
    <label><input class="status_thumb adstatus" type="radio" name="<?php echo $reviewID ?>" value="Rejected" /><img class="rejectimg" src="_source/buttons-assets/rejected.png" width="23" height: "23"></label>
    <label><input class="status_thumb adstatus" type="radio" name="<?php echo $reviewID ?>" value="Approved" /><img class="approveimg" src="_source/buttons-assets/approved.png" width="23" height: "23"></label>
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $uploadID ?>">
    </div>
<?php } while ($row_order_upload = mysql_fetch_assoc($order_upload)); ?>

<input type="submit">
<input type="hidden"  value="revisionRequest">
</form>
```

The above code is written  for each creative uploaded, hope this is enough information for some assistance! Let me know if there is anything else I can provide!

Below is the MySQL code that is being executed for the update, I know it's probably not the best way but that's auto generated from Dreamweaver!:

```
    if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {
  $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE `14111_rfm_uploads` SET file_status=%s WHERE oid=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['file_status'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['oid'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());

  $updateGoTo = "#";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code that is executed when this form is submitted?  That's where the database write will happen, so that's the code that we'll have to analyze and modify.  Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the information with the database code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly your problem but it looks like you want to simply update a database based on user input?

Some hints :

1) Where do you submit your form to? What does your form statement look like

2) Wherever the action of your form points to (e.g. /post/index.php) this files need to take some action on the values your post. To know more about that you need to need to do you can do a var_dump($_POST) on  that page. Most likely you need to leverage PHP PDO to write that data into your database.

Now if you were looking for something that write to the database without posting the form this is called Ajax. Basically with Javascrpit you will submit changes to the database to an other PHP file in the background (as soon as the user click). I'm not sure I would try this approach first if you are not sure  of what you are doing since this is more complexe.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Updated with the function that gets triggered on submit, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Cat the 'a' to the beginning rather than the end of the ID.

```
<?php $reviewID = 'a' . $row_order_upload['id']; ?>
```

Try that etc.